# MongoDB: What does getLastError() return

Tags: java, mongodb

Thought the `WriteResult.getLastError()` should return `null`, if the delete
operation was successful.

It returns this

```
{ "n" : 1 , "connectionId" : 200 , "wtime" : 0 , "err" :  null  , "ok" : 1.0}
```

The `BatchData` `Document` was deleted successfully, but `getLastError()` is not `null`.

How should I write the code to know, if the delete was unsuccessful, in the following snippet:

```java
try {   
  Query<BatchData> queryDeleteBatchData = mongo.createQuery(BatchData.class);   
  queryDeleteBatchData.field("uuid").equal(theBatch.uuid);    
  queryDeleteBatchData.field("senderUuid").equal(on.uuid);   

  WriteResult del = mongo.delete(queryDeleteBatchData);   

  if(del.getLastError() != null){    
     logger.error("ERROR");  
  }   

} catch (Exception e) {
  logger.error("ERROR" );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `getLastError()` command is doing the correct thing. It's telling you that the action was successful (`ok:1.0`) and that no error occurred (`"err":null`).

For more details check out the [recently updated docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/getLastError+Command).

`getLastError()` also has some functionality related to journaling and replication that you  may want to investigate.

---

**Edit:**

In response to the first comment:

```
...
  if(del.getLastError().ok != 1.0){    
     logger.error("ERROR");  
  }   

} catch (Exception e) {
  logger.error("ERROR" );
}
```

Comment: that makes sense of course. How can i rebuild my code to trap the  ("err":null)

Comment: I don't see any documentation regarding the info returned by getLastError in that link.

Comment: This post was answered nearly 2 years ago. So "new" was relative, the docs have been completely re-vamped since then. Going to the new docs and typing `getLastError` into the search bar provided this link: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getLastError/

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-concurrency/#writeconcern-option-for-single-write-operation